# My Background-Image is not being shown

Tags: css

For some reason, my background image is not showing.

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image: url('img/bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Yep. It all looks fine.

Comment: Please complete your question for it to include somewhat of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Is the resource file in the correct directory? Do the developer tools (element inspector) show the expected URL? Have you checked in the developer tools / debugger whether the resource file is actually found (e.g. 200 response)? Is the HTML element containing the background image or the image element itself large enough (check via element inspector) / isn’t obscured by some other element / isn’t otherwise hidden? Is the image normally viewable in the browser or is it corrupted?

Comment: Right click and Inspect Element in Chrome or Firefox, then hover over the source/url to see if it is getting loaded properly. If it is correct then you should see your image appear sort of like a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using URL rewriting make sure you add a slash before the folder name like that :

```
body {
    background-image: url('/img/bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```